From embedded canvas app, how to call javascript defined in model driven form?
In my model driven app, I want to implement several save buttons, which one performs different set of validation. I don't want to do this in the command bar because the number of buttons depends on other variable which I don't get to control if I use the command bar. So I want to implement these save buttons in a embedded canvas app.
According to Microsoft Learn, SaveForm() is one of few things I can do to the hosting form (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/embedded-canvas-app-actions). The documentation doesn't specify, is there other undocumented ways I can take from the canvas app to call a javascript function in the entity form?

Having you tried calling the Main form from a custom page, which is essentially the Power App called from the site map navigation.
using Navigate(Defaults('Your Table')) .
If you have an event handled attached to OnForm load then you can call whatever logic you want on the form.
We backed away from using embedded canvas apps in the way you describe as there  calls to Launch() or Navigate(), gave syntax errors . The same logic when moved to the Custom Page ( Power app) worked like a charm.
